# PHP Form not Uploading all Images to Folder

Tags: php, html, mysql, image

I have a PHP form that is supposed to allow the user to upload 5 images at once. All images should save into my website's folder `images/` when the user hits submit. Currently, only the image in the first image input gets saved into the `images/` folder. The image names are all saved into my MySQL table correctly, though.

Here is the code for my HTML form page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="add.php" method="POST"> 
 Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br> 
 E-mail: <input type="text" name = "email"><br> 
 Phone: <input type="text" name = "phone"><br> 
 Photo: <input type="file" name="photo"><br>
 Photo: <input type="file" name="photo1"><br>
 Photo: <input type="file" name="photo2"><br>
 Photo: <input type="file" name="photo3"><br>
 Photo: <input type="file" name="photo4"><br> 
 <input type="submit" value="Add"> 
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the add.php page code:

```
<?php 

 //This is the directory where images will be saved 
 $target = "images/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); 
  $target1 = "images/"; 
 $target1 = $target1 . basename( $_FILES['photo1']['name']);
   $target2 = "images/"; 
  $target2 = $target2 . basename( $_FILES['photo2']['name']);
    $target3 = "images/"; 
   $target3 = $target3 . basename( $_FILES['photo3']['name']);
     $target4 = "images/"; 
    $target4 = $target4 . basename( $_FILES['photo4']['name']); 
 //This gets all the other information from the form 
 $name=$_POST['name']; 
 $email=$_POST['email']; 
 $phone=$_POST['phone']; 
 $pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']); 
  $pic1=($_FILES['photo1']['name']); 
   $pic2=($_FILES['photo2']['name']); 
    $pic3=($_FILES['photo3']['name']); 
     $pic4=($_FILES['photo4']['name']); 

 // Connects to your Database 
 mysql_connect("dnsacom", "ksbm", "Kszer") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
 mysql_select_db("keabm") or die(mysql_error()) ; 

 //Writes the information to the database 
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `employees` VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$phone', '$pic', '$pic1', '$pic2', '$pic3', '$pic4')") ; 

 //Writes the photo to the server 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 { 

 //Tells you if its all ok 
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
 } 
 else { 

 //Gives and error if its not 
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your image."; 
 }
  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo1']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 { 

 //Tells you if its all ok 
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
 } 
 else { 

 //Gives and error if its not 
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your image."; 
 } 
  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo2']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 { 

 //Tells you if its all ok 
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
 } 
 else { 

 //Gives and error if its not 
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your image."; 
 } 
  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo3']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 { 

 //Tells you if its all ok 
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
 } 
 else { 

 //Gives and error if its not 
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your image."; 
 } 
  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo4']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 { 

 //Tells you if its all ok 
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
 } 
 else { 

 //Gives and error if its not 
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your image."; 
 } 
 ?>
```

Thank you for any help. All help is appreciated.

Comment: My first guess is that the images are too big and/or you're running out of memory on the server. Default upload size is 2 MB per image. How big is each image you're trying to upload?

Comment: The images I am trying to upload are about 15KB to 50KB each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They all have the same `$target` variable. Change your `$target` variables to `$target1`, `$target2`, `$target3` and `$target4` and they'll upload.

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo1']['tmp_name'], $target1)) <--- CHANGE THESE
```

Edit: I tested your code and changed these variables and was able to upload all images.

Answer (score 1):

maybe check map permissions, i recommend checking out chmod, i can't find a problem in your code.

https://www.php.net/chmod
or maybe use brackets since you upload multiple files? like type="file[]"

OW
`if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo1']['tmp_name'], $target))` problem solved you use $target everywhere which is why only 1 picture gets uploaded

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with how to use brackets. I will however check out chmod, as you suggested.

Comment: just a small question, are you doing this code locally, so server is running on your pc(xampp/wampp) and pictures are uploading locally, or are you using a real server, if it is the second answer then chmod could help you, if it is the first it would be unlikely.

Comment: I am using a real server. I don't think changing the file type of the images is the solution to my problem because as I already stated, the first image is uploading fine into the folder. It is the other images that I am having the issue with.

Comment: cool for the real server, but more ontopic, i think you should use an array, or upload them in a for loop, idk if it fixes your problem but its a very strange problem to me so worth a try i geuss. also does it even echo photo 1/2/3/4